# Refering JS and CSS file after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, angular-translate

Iam building a mobile App which has multi-lingual feature.Iam using angularjs and jQueryMobile framework for this.I have successfully managed to change language from english to arabic.Since arabic is right to left language I need script file and css file such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"/>
```

And for english my js and script file are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
```

Iam loading the script and css inside head tag.

I have two buttons such below

```
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('ar')"  translate="BUTTON_TEXT_DE"></button>
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_TEXT_EN"></button>
```

in my index file.
If i click the first button the script for arabic should be refered
If i click the second button the script for english should be refered

How do I achieve this.Please help.Iam new to angularjs.Any type of suggestion is welcomed.Thank you

Comment: why not try reloading the page after clicking. and handle the things server side.

Comment: The app is an offline application.i cant depend on server for anything

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to dynamically load JS and CSS. So try something like this
[Dynamically loading JS and CSS](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate.I have already checked that link...it didnt work for me